# where to unlock mutex in pthread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Is it a good practice to lock a mutex from the main thread, and release from another thread?

Or should I make sure a thread will do it all in one? ie: lock, and unlock

Comment: This question is not great by any means, but why did it deserve a -1? +1 to compensate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mutex can only be unlocked by the same thread that locked it. A program that violates this rule has **undefined behavior** and is not portable or stable; it may seem to work at times and fail horribly at other times, when compiled on a slightly different system, during a different phase of the moon, or after you upgrade.

If you really need this sort of behavior (locking by one thread and unlocking by another), a semaphore may meet your needs. Semaphores do not have owners, and any thread may call `sem_post` or `sem_wait` at basically any time.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock/

(also from the POSIX spec site: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

> If the current thread holds the lock on mutex, then the
>   **pthread_mutex_unlock()** function unlocks mutex.
>
> Calling **pthread_mutex_unlock()** with a mutex that the calling thread
>   does not hold will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but I suggest referencing the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) rather than "manpagez.com".  (The spec is normative.)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to lock in one thread and unlock in another thread as this will require the two threads to communicate with each other. A thread should perform its own locking and unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

It's never good practice to lock from one thread and unlock from another.  The name says it all -- mutual exclusion.  A thread that takes it holds it until done.